# Android.mk: как правильно присоединить динамическую библиотеку?

Tags: android, android-ndk, build

Есть библиотека, назовем ее `Library.so` и инклуды к ней. Без `jni`. Нужно присоединить ее к проекту. Для этого пишу `jni` обертку.
Собираю все следующим образом (`Android.mk`):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Library
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Library.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Library_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Library_jni.c 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi/libLibrary.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Все собирается нормально, но при выполнении:

```
static
{
    try{
            System.loadLibrary("Library_jni");
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError use){
        Log.e("JNI","ERROR: Could not load Library_jni.so");
    }
}
```

сообщение об ошибке выводится. Если не отлавливать, вылетает с исключением:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]: 69 could not load needed library 'libLibrary.so' for 'libLibrary_jni.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libLibrary.so' not found)
```

То есть библиотека-обертка не может загрузиться, потому что на найдена основная библиотека. Как я понимаю, она ищется по адресу: `$(LOCAL_PATH)/../libs/armeabi/libLibrary.so`, но на устройстве, само собой такой папки нет. На устройстве библиотеки лежат в `data/data/my.package/lib`. Понятно, что она и не найдется.

Но при любом другом адресе в `LOCAL_LDLIBS` линковщик не может найти нужный файл, сборка завершается с ошибкой. Если писать только

```
LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := libLibrary
```

линковщик не видит реализаций функций из внутренней библиотеки, заголовки видит нормально.
Как правильно сослаться на динамическую библиотеку из другой динамической библиотеки, чтобы и на этапе сборки и на этапе выполнения не было ошибок? Можно сделать так, чтобы при сборке библиотека искалась по одному адресу, а при выполнении по другому?

Comment: о таких вещах лучше спрашивать на stackoverflow.com

Comment: Я там пыталась читать, ничего не вычитала. Но у нас же местный stackoverflow, вдруг кто-нибудь знает.

Comment: проверяйте пути. А лучше найдите готовый настроенный проект-шаблон и компилируйте. Пути на девайсе не как не влияют на пути в проекте. Что-то с путями не то явно, либо название. Найдите шаблонный проект и используйте его, благо в инете такого масса.

Comment: в семплах к ндк есть же пример two-libs, он вам не помог, или вы его не смотрели?

Comment: @IronVbif, в two-libs сначала строится статическая библиотека, а потом она включается в динамическую. А у меня внутренняя - динамическая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, нужно подгружать библиотеки так:

```
static
{
    try{    
        System.loadLibrary("Library");
        System.loadLibrary("Library_jni");
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError use){
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Тогда все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что загрузчик Андроида автоматически [не подгружает](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34416) зависимости. То есть если библиотека А зависит от библиотеки Б, то пользователь должен самостоятельно грузить библиотеку Б до библиотеки А.

Вы можете обойти ограничение, если

1. либо внедрите JNI в основную библиотеку,
2. либо загрузите вручную (dlopen, dlclose) основную библиотеку из вспомогательной.

Comment: 1. Невозможно, нет исходного кода основной библиотеки.
2. Может быть. Но почему ошибка появляется при попытке загрузить внешнюю библиотеку, а не при попытке вызвать функцию из внутренней? Где тогда загружать вручную, в какой момент?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.